# Удаление нескольких селекторов одной функцией

Tags: jquery

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста, как удалить сразу несколько селекторов.

[Моя идея](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4bdz/), того чего хочу (понятное дело, что не работает):

```
$('.some_class_one', '.some_class_two', 'div #some_id', 'p some-text'). remove();
```

Comment: запятые оставьте, кавычки внутри уберите.

подозрительно выглядит 'div #some_id' , id обычно уникальный и соответственно родителей ему указывать не надо.

Comment: нуда нуда, заработало ))) спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

так попробуйте:

```
$('.some_class_one, .some_class_two, div #some_id, p some-text').remove();
```

Comment: удалился только первый элемент, я [тут][1] пример сделал


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/Y4bdz/

Comment: ааа все заработало!! )) Спасибо!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Y4bdz/1/